# Requiring valid input with cout/cin

Tags: c++

I have a game where the user needs to enter x and y coordinates within a certain range, one at a time. Right now my input code is as follows:

```
do {
    printf("\n");
    cout << "X: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Y: ";
    cin >> y;
} while (cin.fail());
```

I'm new to c++ but reading documentation lead me to believe this was an acceptable method for verifying user input. It works perfectly when the input is valid, however when the input is of a different type (for instance entering "a") it infinitely loops with "X: Y: ". What do I need to do differently to have it wait for user input as if the lines were being read for the first time?

Comment: There are duplicates, but you need to check for success, clear bad flags, and discard bad input.

Comment: See this FAQ: [How can I get `std::cin` to skip invalid input characters?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html)

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks! I got things working now. Still have a lot to learn..

Comment: Always ask yourself if your program works when invoked like `echo abc | ./myprog`. It should behave meaningfully and not blow up the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest problem with trying to parse per variable is that when a user makes a mistake, their whole input becomes suspect.

Consider if I skip invalid input and enter: "3e4 40".  I meant "34 40", but skipping the e might make "3 4" and leave "40" for later or might leave "4 40".

Consider using [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read a whole line in and parsing it such as with [istringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) just as you are now -- any error becomes an error without leaving the inputstream in a weird state.

Comment: @jons34yp Do you have a suggestion for a site with specific references where you can't find a lot of errors?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com has a good reputation among stackoverflow users. So far I haven't found any discrepancies between that site and the standard either..

Comment: @jons34yp Changed links in message.  Next time, please suggest that site in favor of the other.

Answer (score 5):

You should check every single input operation:

```
std::cout << "X: ";
if (!(std::cin >> x)) { /* error */ }
std::cout << "Y: ";
if (!(std::cin >> y)) { /* error */ }
```

It's up to you how you want to handle the error. You could return early, break from a loop, throw an exception... it all depends.

Note that you *could* loop until you get something parseable, but that's dangerous if the user closes the input stream. Better to read line by line and parse:

```
std::cout << "Please enter an integer X: ";
int x;
bool success = false;

for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    if (iss >> x >> std::ws && iss.get() == EOF)  // #1
    {
        success = true;
        break;
    }
    std::cout << "Sorry, please try again: ";
}

if (!success)
{
    std::cerr << "Unexpected end of input stream!\n";
    std::exit(1);
}
```

This way, if the user presses [Ctrl]-D in the middle of the session, the program shuts down immediately and doesn't try to read more values from the closed input stream.

The condition on the line marked `#1` tests both for a successful parsing of an integer as well as for having reached the end of the line (gobbling intermediate whitespace).